# Memory leak - a simple phpinfo() page increases container memory usage

Tags: php, apache-2.4, docker, lamp

I have a [PHP Info](https://www.thalasoft.com:83/phpinfo.php) page containing the following:

```
<?php
print(phpinfo());
?>
```

But every time the page is reloaded, a `docker stats` commands shows that  the memory usage goes up by 0.25%

I have custom built the images for `httpd` and `php` as well as `mariadb` and a few others.

The memory percentage does not ever go down. If doing nothing it stays stable and does not go up. If sending a request does it go up a bit. Even if waiting for a long time, the memory percentage usage doesn't go down.

The process is the `httpd/php` process and I do not use the `mpm_prefork_module` module.

One thing to note is that the memory usage increase is even greater (some 2%) when sending a request to my own PHP application.

I built the Docker images myself on `httpd 2.4.25` and `php 7.3.9` running under Docker version: `19.03.2`.

I could post the `Dockerfile` files if needed.

Comment: Any language with garbage collection mechanism works that way, and the memory is only reclaimed when it is really necessary, https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.gc.performance-considerations.php If you never learn any GC based language in the past, I think now is the time.

Comment: As is stated in the question, the memory usage never ever goes down once it went up.